# Ember JS and templating "Template not found"

Tags: javascript, ember.js, templating

So i have these script includes:

```
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.7.3/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

This in my head tag:

```
        <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
            WTF

        </script>
```

And this in my main.js:

```
window.Stocks = Ember.Application.create();

Stocks.Router = Em.Router.extend({
    initialState: 'root.home',
    root: Em.Route.extend({
        home: Em.Route.extend({
            view: Stocks.CurrentStocksView
        })
    })
});

Stocks.CurrentStocksView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'application',
    appendTo: function() {
        this._super('#current');
    }
});


// Startup call
Stocks.initialize();
```

And i've totally lost the way. I just want to print "WTF" bewteen the . And do i need to include the script tag voor handlebars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you seems to use `ember 1.0.0-pre2`. So you don't have to specify `Stocks.initialize()` unless you set the `autoinit` `Ember.Application` property to false:

```
Stocks = Ember.Application.create({
  autoinit: false
});

// omitted code

Stocks.initialize(); // needed because the app is not automatically initialized
```

Next, you should include `Handlebars` before loading ember:

```
<script src="js/vendor/handlebars-1.0.rc.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/vendor/ember-1.0.0-pre.2.min.js"></script>
```

And it should work, as you can see [in this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BWUCA/).

Comment: In your JSFiddle, you don't set the framework (onLoad) to `jQuery`. See the same JSFiddle with jQuery loaded: http://jsfiddle.net/27crF/1/

Comment: I think i found the problem. I used Modernizr to a-sync load all javascript, but somehow it causes Ember/Handlebars not to process or find the templates. Thanks for your help, you gave me hope and the last push :)